# How to stop <li> elements from overlapping?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my code

```css
ul li{
    display:inline;
  }
li {

    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: Bisque ;
}
```

```html
<div class="fr_station">
        <span id="route">
    <?php
    // print_r($route);

    $pLine = 0;
    $cLine = 0;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($route as $value) {

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,'select station,line,stnCode from stn_name where stnCode='.$value.' LIMIT 1') or die(mysqli_error());
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<li>".$res['station']."</li>";
         //echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 3); 

        if (!isset($previous)) {
            $previous = $source;
            $present = $source;
        } else {
            $current = $value;
            $d_result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM alt_station_data WHERE stnCode ='.$previous.' AND nei='.$current.' LIMIT 1');
            $d_res = mysqli_fetch_array($d_result);
            $tot_dist += $d_res['dis'];
            $previous = $value;
            echo "</tr>";
            $floored = floor($tot_dist);
        }

    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
```

When I am printing the elements then the elements from 2nd line is overlapping with the ones on the first line and so on at the end of the line it is printing half content on one line and remaining content on next line.

[image]

Comment: Use inline-block instead of inline.

Comment: or increase the line-height

Comment: For future reference, when you ask a css question, it is better to create a [mcve] using the rendered html - only post the raw php when you are stuck with php code

Comment: CBroe: specifically, use * display:inline-block; *.
Also, somewhere in the middle you echo "</tr>"; Since there's not a table in sight, this may be a typo.

Comment: @realbart the is a common issue of padding with inline element : https://jsfiddle.net/vsq4xjdb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By using `inline` each `li` behaves like a word so doesn’t have it’s own ‘box’. `inline-block` lets them sit side-by-side but gives each one it’s own ‘box’.

If you need even more control then start looking at flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout but don’t forget you will need `flex-wrap: wrap`

On a side note, with your example it would be easier if you just provide the outputted HTML without the php code as that’s not required. :)

Comment: Thanks for flex-box suggestion.It worked

Comment: @AkhilSharma I am pleased it worked. You should mark it as the correct answer so anyone finding this post in the future knows it works. :)